# How old does a GitHub account need to be to be trusted for deploy on Railway

Tags: github, hosting, telegram-bot, railway

When you deploy a Python telegram bot from GitHub on Railway hosting, you get the error:

> Your GitHub Can't Be Verified. Your GitHub might be too new or there might be risky repos on your account that means you can't verify with your GitHub.

Most likely the account is too new, just like the error says. What to do and/or how long to wait before I can deploy bot from GitHub repository on hosting with Railway?

I tried to relocate the bot to another hosting, but it did not work. Moreover, I want to choose Railway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account needs to be at least 90 days old to be able to use the first starter tier. And if you have a history of actively committing which is at least 6 months old then you can gain access to the next tier.